# How to allow DIV tags in Yii2 Editor

Tags: yii2, redactor

I installed a blog module that allows me to add blogs to my Yii2 app. Everything works well except the editor. I think Yii2 by default uses redactor.
The problem is that when I add code with using the code interface, all DIV tags are converted automatically to P tags.
[image: Screenshot of editor]

I have checked through the redactor configuration but it does not look like there is a setting to adjust this:

```
    'redactor' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
        'uploadDir' => '@frontend/images/blog/upload',
        'uploadUrl' => '/sites/eop/frontend/images/blog/upload',
        'imageAllowExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg'],
    ],
```

Any idea on where else to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `replaceDivs` option, and set it to `false` under the client options. See the below code for an example

```
<?php echo \yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::widget(
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'body',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'replaceDivs' => false
        ]
    ]
);
?>
```

if you are using an `ActiveForm` it should be like

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(
    [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'replaceDivs' => false
        ]
    ]
);
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly well. This is what I was looking for = `'replaceDivs' => false`. Please share if there is a link where one can get the list of all available options. Thanks

Comment: it depends which version the extension is using and the documentation does not seem to be complete i looked up in the unminified version of the plugin provided in the source for the options and there it is on line [123](https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-redactor/blob/master/assets/redactor.js#L123) , it is using 10.2.2 version. it is always a good idea to go through the available options in the source code , if you are not finding anything over the internet @atsngr

Comment: Thanks for the link @Muhammad Omer Aslam. Very helpful.